# Changing MS of setInterval depending on a condition

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the speed at which my program will iterate through my array and put info into my text area. But I don't think I understand the functionality of setInterval and setTimeout perfectly, or maybe its something else, I'm very new to JS.

```
var theStage,getDrop,getSize,time,isChecked,turbo; 

function changeFrame(stopper){
if(isChecked === true){
    turbo = 50;
    }
else{
    turbo = 250;
    }
time = setInterval(start, turbo);
}

function start(){
    var frames = theStage.value.split("=====\n");
    var i = 0, l = frames.length;
    (function iterator() {
        theStage.value = frames[i];

        if(++i<l) {
            setTimeout(iterator, turbo);
        }
    })();
};
```

Comment: And what's your question/problem? Doesn't your code works as it is supposed to? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: So basically as far as I'm concerned, what I'm trying to do it make the process of printing out the entirety of what my start() function does faster. It doesn't do this, evidently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` and `setInterval` are creating a new timer each time you call them. If you want to have one timer, but change how often it's executed, then you need to remove it and "set" with a new time, like this:

```
var timer = null;

...

// Each time, before creating a new timer, remove the old one.
if (timer !== null)
    clearInterval(timer)
timer = setInterval(...);
```

I think, that your code can be simplified to use only one timer:

```
var theStage, isChecked, delay;
var frames = theStage.value.split("=====\n");
var progress = 0, l = frames.length;

function changeSpeed() {
    if (isChecked)
        delay = 50;
    else
        delay = 250;
}

function processFrame() {
    theStage.value = frames[progress];

    if (++progress < l)
        // Recursively call self until whole list of frames is processed.
        setTimeout(processFrame, delay);
}
```

When you use `setTimeout` to create recursive function then you don't need to reset timer.